# NotReadablePropertyException while using projection on EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I have the following problem with using Spring Data on EclipseLink - I use projections in order to get selected properties of the objects in database. I have an entity named "Campaign":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign")
public class Campaign implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    private CampaignState state = CampaignState.NEW;

    // getters and setters...

}
```

CampaignState is some enum. Then, I added the following projection:

```
public interface CampaignStateView {
    CampaignState getState();
}
```

...which I use in my repository:

```
public interface CampaignRepository extends
        JpaRepository<Campaign, String>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Campaign> {

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT c.state AS state FROM Campaign c")
    List<CampaignStateView> findDistinctStates();
}
```

I use this repository in my service:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CampaignDataService {

    private CampaignRepository campaignRepository;

    // for CDI proxy
    public CampaignDataService() {
    }

    @Inject
    public CampaignDataService(CampaignRepository campaignRepository) {
        this.campaignRepository = campaignRepository;
    }

    public Collection<CampaignState> findStates() {
        return campaignRepository.findDistinctStates().stream()
                .map(CampaignStateView::getState)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

But, unfortunately, when I call a method findStates() from the service, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'state' of bean class [campaign.CampaignState]: Could not find field for property during fallback access! 
     at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.getPropertyValue(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:58) 
     at org.springframework.data.projection.PropertyAccessingMethodInterceptor.invoke(PropertyAccessingMethodInterceptor.java:73) 
     at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:64) 
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) 
     at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:245) 
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) 
     at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) 
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) 
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) 
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy301.getState(Unknown Source) 
     at campaign.CampaignDataService$$Lambda$491.000000006DCDF7C0.apply(Unknown Source) 
     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:204) 
     at java.util.Vector$VectorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Vector.java:1451) 
     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:523) 
     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513) 
     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:719) 
     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:245) 
     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:510) 
     at campaign.CampaignDataService.findStates(CampaignDataService.java:153)
     ... 118 more
```

I get this error only on EclipseLink - on Hibernate everything works fine...

Comment: Can you please share the exact version of EclipseLink in which you are observing this?

Comment: It would seem Spring Data is trying to access the `state` property on `CampaignState` rather than `Campaign`. My guess is it's because you're selecting a single property only. Does it work when you change `List<CampaignStateView>` to `List<CampaignState>`?

Comment: @MWiesner EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.7.WAS-v20180710-6c446ab

Comment: @crizzis it won't work in Spring Data

Comment: How do you mean? Are you getting a different error?

Comment: Is it possible to extract one field only without projections in Spring Data?

Comment: Well, why don't you try it?

Comment: Yeah, it worked without projections... Even though, I don't understand why projections don't work...

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown when the Object (CampaignState) will be null. Please verify if you are having valid values for it. 
As per the code and Line where the error is being thrown in DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.Java class :

```
@Override
public Object getPropertyValue(String propertyName) {
    try {
        return super.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
    } catch (NotReadablePropertyException e) {
        Field field = findField(getWrappedClass(), propertyName);
        if (field == null) {
            throw new NotReadablePropertyException(getWrappedClass(), propertyName, "Could not find field for property during fallback access!");
        }
        makeAccessible(field);
        return getField(field, getWrappedInstance());
    }
}
```

The NotReadablePropertyException will be thrown if field is null.
Most probably the value coming from campaignRepository.findDistinctStates() is null.

Comment: Hi, no, you are wrong. I have to repeat - it works on Hibernate. You found right piece of code, but the problem is that getWrappedClass() returns CampaignState, but it should return CampaignStateView. CampaignState doesn't have state field, this is why field is null and exception is thrown.

Comment: May be EclipseLink is parsing the data differently. The return type of getState method is CampaignState, that might be the issue. Try creating a class CampaignStateView for the API to wrap to that type or having a filed state type as CampaignState in CampaignStateView. I dont see any other reason for it to fail.